# Method with equals sign not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller with some dummy methods to test why this isn't working (seen in Rails 4):

```
class Foo::BarController < ApplicationController
  before_action :foo

protected

  def foo
    session[:foo] ||= rand(100)
    bar
  end

  def foo=(n)
    puts "Reassigning foo"
    session[:foo] = n
  end

  def bar
    foo=(33)
    puts "Session is #{session[:foo]}"
  end
```

When I visit any routes in a controller that inherits from `Foo::BarController`, the logs show e.g. `Session is 12`, and the `foo=` method is never evaluated.

How do I get this setter method to fire?

Comment: @MurifoX I didn't quite get when you say `and your attribute the same`?

Comment: Nevermind my comment. =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `foo=` as `self.foo=` as shown below.

```
  def bar
    self.foo=(33)
    puts "Session is #{session[:foo]}"
  end
```

Without `self`, `foo` was treated as `local variable` and the method `foo=` was never invoked.